# How to calculate memory for a table?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

Consider am having a database with a table contains 2 fields of integer,string. Can anyone plz tell how to calculate memory for a table in database in terms of KB. Is there any generic formula available to calculate ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the string fixed width or variable width? If it is variable then the size depends on the strings' sizes